# PSObject too large to measure or load

Tags: powershell

I am tying to get some data from a webserver and run into an issue where I cannot process the return object correctly as PowerShell just seems to wait for it to load indefinitely.

```
# Get a HtmlWebResponseObject    
$Root = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri  $BaseUrl -SessionVariable 'Session'
```

On most web pages I can then interact with the resulting object:

```
PS> $Root | Measure 

Count    : 1
Average  : 
Sum      : 
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property : 

PS> $Root.Links | Measure  

Count    : 412
Average  : 
Sum      : 
Maximum  : 
Minimum  : 
Property :
```

However, in some cases the call to `$Root.Links | Measure` seems to freeze PowerShell. Even trying to copy this to another object with `$Links = $Root.Links` locks PowerShell up (I let it sit for over an hour). Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to cancel is the only way to interact with the PowerShell window again. The funny thing is that copying the entire object `$Root1 = $Root` does work

How would I be able to analyze what is going wrong? Memory levels for my `powershell.exe` do not exceed 70 MB, so that seems reasonable to me.

Comment: Can you output the content of $Root to a file?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I tried to send it to a file with `$Root | Out-File 'C:\temp\root'` but it also locks up loading / reading from $Root.   The workaround I have now is to manually grab the .Content and use a RegEx expression to grab the links from the web page. That works just fine, so I expect there might be an issue with the `Invoke-WebRequest` return object.

Comment: Are you able to just inspect root, by typing in `$Root`?

Comment: AP, I tried that too with no luck.